# How to align images to the right but also align them center-wise relative to each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I currently have this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-warning">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light text-right">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F0d%2FRed_blue_circle.svg%2F1200px-Red_blue_circle.svg.png&f=1" style="max-height: 18px; width: 25px">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-warning">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light text-right">
      <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F0d%2FRed_blue_circle.svg%2F1200px-Red_blue_circle.svg.png&f=1" style="max-height: 18px; width: auto">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see the images are to the right of the 3rd column, which is what I want. But I also need the images to be aligned relative to their center, like this:
[image]

Comment: `margin-right: 3px` to the image in the second row...

Comment: I can't do that since I am actually generating each row inside a `for loop`. I tried to provide a simple example in my question which doesn't show that.

Comment: To have the images aligned relative to eachother they would need to have a parent in common. I'm thinking you will probably need to redesign the html so that dynamically added images are added to the same container element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all of the image widths, you can wrap each image in a div with the width set to the max image width and text-center. To pull them to the right, you can add d-flex and justify-content-end to the parent column

For example

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-warning">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light d-flex justify-content-end ">
      <div style="width: 25px;" class="text-center">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F0d%2FRed_blue_circle.svg%2F1200px-Red_blue_circle.svg.png&f=1" style="max-height: 18px; width: 25px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-warning">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div style="width: 25px;" class="text-center">
        <img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F0%2F0d%2FRed_blue_circle.svg%2F1200px-Red_blue_circle.svg.png&f=1" style="max-height: 18px; width: auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```